# Numerically calculating the Jacobian for this function

Tags: matlab, jacobian

I have a function of the form -

$F = \phi u + \frac{1}{2} \frac{d^2u}{dt^2} + |u|^2u $ where $u = u(t)$ is a complex-valued vector of length $N$ and $\phi$ is a variable (single number).

I would like to find the root ($F=0$) of this function using Newton's method (which is probably not the best technique, but I'd like to try it anyway). The solution is expected to calculate both $\phi$ and $u(t)$.

This is not a deterministic system of equations because there is one variable more than the number of equations. This system has a solution $u = sech(t)$ and $\phi = -0.5$ which can be confirmed through substitution.

My problem at the moment is in finding the Jacobian of the system, specifically when it involves the second term in the function (the second derivative of $u$).

Here's what I have done so far -

$\frac{d}{du}\frac{d^2u}{dt^2} = \frac{dt}{du}\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}) = \frac{dt}{du}\frac{d^3u}{dt^3}$.

I tried implementing the right side by doing the following -

First, I calculate $\frac{du}{dt}$ and then do a 1./(dudt) on MATLAB. Then I perform element-wise multiplication of that with $\frac{d^3}{dt^3}$. This yields many NaN terms which is not very surprising.

I am not sure how to proceed now. I'd appreciate any hints/solutions or even possible alternatives to find the root of my function.

Comment: You seem to be confusing a few things. As it stands, $\phi$, $u$, and $u''$ can take on any values. You want to compute the Hessian with respect to the unknowns.

Comment: The Hessian? That would be to find the minima of the function, right? I want to find the root (F = 0), which would require the Jacobian. I could be wrong (very new to this field and linear algebra). If I am indeed wrong, could you explain why I need the Hessian? Also, how would I calculate the Jacobian (or Hessian)?